TKINTER GUI not responding
As soon as I click the button with a command linked to a function, Tkinter GUI freezes and goes to not responding mode. I am not getting any error but also I am not getting any output.
        def SBPRM(self):

            premium_acc_data_path = r'' + self.entry_fields[0].get()
            tagging_data_path = r'' + self.entry_fields[1].get()
            desc_acc_data_path = r'' + self.entry_fields[4].get()
            hr_data_path = r'' + self.entry_fields[2].get()
            iibf_data_path = r'' + self.entry_fields[3].get()
            claw_back = int(self.entry_fields[5].get())

these files are pretty big and the almost 200 lines of codes after these which would manipulate the data and save it as a excel file in downloads. What should I do? so that these files will be read using pd.read and the data gets manipulated properly

Please show your function that runs when you click on the button and the button definition

Use thread for fix freeze. Big files slow GUI. Here example:
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd

def SBPRM():
    paths = [entry_fields[i].get() for i in range(6)]
    thread = threading.Thread(target=process_data, args=paths)
    thread.start()

def process_data(*paths):
    premium_data = pd.read_csv(paths[0])
    tagging_data = pd.read_csv(paths[1])
    # Your long data processing code here

# Tkinter setup code here

This make GUI not freeze.
